# What ids are in onUpdate's appWidgetIds[]?

Tags: android, background, android-appwidget, identifier

Do the ids in the array **appWidgetIds** of the method

> public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager
>   appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

all belong to my app?

If so then there are some appwidgets somewhere in the nirvana of my android, because if I delete all appwidgets there still remain some ids in the array which are not shown on my homescreen. :-(

Is there a way to remove ALL widgets?

Comment: I remember seeing something similar...  IIRC, I just had wrap it in a try/catch or something if the appWidgetId was invalid.  Anyone have a real solution?

Comment: Just getting a "valid" appwidgetid is not my worry. I'm furthermore  concerned if I created any invisible widgets. Because if I now create a new weidget it's id apears and ifI remove it, its id disappears. But what are these other ids where there is no (visible) widget?

Comment: Ah, perhaps I was seeings something different, then.  Mine would sometimes (but not always) stick around after being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved: I uninstalled, then reinstalled my app and after that all the *ghost widgets* were gone.

In conclusion: **all the ids in appWidgetIds are the ids of my app**.

Answer (score 5):

Weeelp, I've returned to Android development 8 years later (was surprised to find I already commented on this question), and now I have a real answer.  It seems to have only become better-known years after this question was originally posted, but basically:  There's a bug in Android that's remained unfixed pretty much forever.

All those phantom IDs are the appWidgetIds of widgets you started to creat at some point, *but were incorrectly canceled on the widget configuration activity*.

Over on the [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#Configuring), it includes this code sample for confirming creation of an widget:

```
Intent resultValue = new Intent();
resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
finish();
```

Read the tip below it carefully:

> Tip: When your configuration Activity first opens, set the Activity result to RESULT_CANCELED, along with EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, as shown in step 5 above. This way, if the user backs-out of the Activity before reaching the end, the App Widget host is notified that the configuration was cancelled and the App Widget will not be added.

While Android accepts `setResult(RESULT_CANCEL);` (and plenty of tutorials use it and I believe even the official documentation once had sample code like this), it's wrong.  Without passing along the new ID, it remains in the system as one of those mysterious phantom IDs.

The correct way to cancel creating a widget is `setResult(RESULT_CANCEL, resultValue);`

Answer (score 1):

ur app widget can have multiple widgets for the same app, say one widget showing location, one widget showing stocks, one widget showing blah blah,
in such cases, each widget can be assigned an ID called appWidgetID

Comment: That wasn't really the answere to my question. I knew that I can use multiple widgets. But anyhow I got it solved: I uninstalled and then reinstalled my app and after that all the ghost widgets were gone. So all the ids in appWidgetIds are ids of my App.

Comment: @LordFlash , you should post this as an answer. I faced same problem and ur offer was the solution.